# Collect Lines using Multimap Collector

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, guava, multimap, collectors

Is there a way to covert the below to using collectors yet?

```
List<String[]> lines = getLines();

Multimap<String,String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

lines.forEach(line -> 
multimap.put(line[0],line[1]);
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Multimaps.toMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#toMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) collector:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = lines.stream()
        .collect(Multimaps.toMultimap(
                l -> l[0],
                l -> l[1],
                ArrayListMultimap::create
        ));
```

Or if you don't need mutability, use [`ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = lines.stream()
        .collect(toImmutableListMultimap(l -> l[0], l -> l[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for =)